# JSON decoding by Oj converts a string into other object

Tags: ruby, json, string, symbols

I am using the Oj gem to decode JSON strings into Ruby objects. When I have an encoded string as in the example below, it is decoded as intended:

```
require "oj"
Oj.load("\"a\"") # => "a"
```

but when the original string starts with a colon, the decoding process converts it into a symbol:

```
Oj.load("\":a\"") # => :a
```

I expected to get a string `":a"` in this case. Are there other cases where the Oj gem converts a string into something else? How can I avoid these cases where it converts strings into other objects?

Comment: @theTinMan You frequently seem to edit and add question marks to titles where putting one is grammatically wrong. What is that? In this particular case, it can be understood as a half-question sentence read with a rising tone, and is not as worse as many other cases you edit, but was it necessary at all? I recognize you corrected my mistake in number agreement in the text, and that was appreciated, but your adding the question mark always seems strange. I don't want to sound stupid like all those people on this site who puts a question mark even on an embedded question.

Comment: Questions *always* end with a question mark. That is part of English grammar. http://www.scribendi.com/advice/question_mark.en.html and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35806/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-question-without-a-question-mark. "I don't want to sound stupid like all those people on this site who puts a question mark even on an embedded question.", well, embedded questions can have question marks, because, again, they are questions. A question mark can substitute for a comma in an embedded question. Without "?" it's an exclamation using "!" or statement.

Comment: First of all, many of the phrases you put question marks on are not questions, they are just phrases. Second, questions (more accurately, interrogative clauses) do not always end with a question mark. Only matrix questions do. It is surprising to me that you do not seem to know this rule. What you mentioned as "embedded question" is actually a **directly quoted** matrix question. It is not an embedded question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oj is not [strict mode by default](https://github.com/ohler55/oj#description) which means it converts anything into Ruby equivalents.
You can set it via the `default_options` hash

```
Oj.default_options[:mode] = :strict
```

Otherwise using `Oj.strict_load("\":a\"")` will produce the string `:a`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion using `strict_load` worked, but changing the default option and using `load` did not work.

Comment: `Oj.default_options = {:mode => :strict }; Oj.load("\":a\"").class //=> String` worked for me.

Comment: You are right. There seems to be a difference between `Oj.default_options[:mode] = :strict` and `Oj.default_options = {:mode => :strict }`. Is this perhaps a bug?

Comment: I've tweeted the author and asked. Waiting reply, you can follow along at @webhenrik